# Xamarin.Android Exclude specific assembly from linking

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-linker

I updated my xamarin.android packages to the latest version and make the target framework is AndroidQ
but now I can't build the project when used Linker properties "SDK Assemblies only"

how I can exclude monkeyCache.SqlLite from linking assemblies

[image]

Comment: You could set the Linker to none, If you still have this issue.

Comment: Did you find how to fix it? Also, @LeonLu-MSFT, your solution might work but can make the APK significantly bigger like in my case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68526148/how-can-i-correctly-exclude-some-libraries-so-that-they-are-not-linked-in-xamari

It's not exactly a good solution if you're not open to having considerable APKs to distribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude assemblies from linking

- editing .csproj file :

`<PropertyGroup><AndroidLinkSkip>MvvmCross;MvvmCross.Plugin.Messenger</AndroidLinkSkip>`

- via project properties -> Android Options
  [image]

Comment: I already added MonkeyCache.SQLite and MonkeyCache still have the same issue